# JSmooth generated exe does not show Splash Screen

Tags: java, swing, splash-screen, jsmooth

I wrap my Java Swing application as an exe using Jsmooth but I can see no way to take advantage of Java 6 splash screen option. I have the following manifest file:

```
     Manifest-Version: 1.0

     SplashScreen-Image: resources/LOADLOGO.png

     Main-Class: se.bookingapp.UI.MainFrame
```

The splash screen appears if I simply click on the jar file of the application. However, the JSmooth generated exe form of the jar file does not show the splash screen somehow. Does anyone know why?

Comment: "resource" folder and "LOADLOGO.png", where are they? Maybe, you need to tell the structure of your installation folder.

Comment: I generated the exe file using Launch4j and it worked. Pitty that JSmooth cannot do this.

Comment: Yeah, I also use Launch4J which is more reliable every time I use it, together with InnoSetup + Ant task

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does it work when you execute the jar file? Open it with WinRar for example, and check if the manifest is into  META-INF folder, and LOADLOGO.png is in the right folder too.

After doing that, it should work. It works for me. Nothing wrong in your manifest.

Answer (score 2):

Yesterday I've finished to develop my java application and I had the same issue. If I double click the .jar file or I execute in a command line splash screen works perfectly, but when I execute the wrapped file it doesn't. Seems just JSmooth doesn't support this feature.

However I made a little trick to have a wrapped `.exe` and splash screen working at the same time. I made a little application called `ApplicationLoader.jar` that consists in a single main class that execute `java -jar "Application.jar"` in a command line. Here is the complete code:

```
public class ApplicationLoader {
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {        
    /* First I check if the first parameter is not null and it's not an empty string */
    if(args[0] != null && !args[0].trim().isEmpty()){
        /* Then I use java.util.regex package to validate the parameter is a .jar file */
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*jar");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(args[0]);            
        if(matcher.matches()){
            /* Finally I define the command line like: java -jar "Application.jar" */
            String command = "java -jar \"" + args[0] + "\"";
            try {
                Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
                ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/c", command);
                Process p = pb.start();
                p.waitFor();
                } catch (IOException | InterruptedException ex) {
                   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage(), "Error executing: "+command, JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                }                
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The argument is not a .jar file!!");
        }            
    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "There's not a valid argument!");
    }
}
}
```

I have this folder structure for my application:

> ```
> MyApp
>   +-- bin
>   |    +-- MyApp.jar
>   |    +-- ApplicationLoader.jar
>   +-- MyApp.exe
> ```

So in `JSmoot` I changed the classpath to `ApplicationLoader.jar` and add the relative location to my application in *Application Arguments* section like this:

[image]

And that's it. I know this is not the best option but is a workaround.

However there's a little problem:

Since `ApplicationLoader.jar` calls a `cmd.exe` then the wrapped `.exe` and your application will execute in two different processes.

This implies that if you have to kill `.exe` process for some reason (unexpected crash or something), your java application still working as a `java.exe` process. So in that case you must kill `MyApp.exe` and `java.exe` processes. Actually if you just kill `java.exe` process then `MyApp.exe` process will finish execution by itself.

If you keep this in mind and you can live with that I think this option is quite simple and useful.
I hope this be helpful to anybody looking for a workaround to this issue.